# How to install h264 codec for python av, on Mac OS X

Tags: python, macos, libav

I've got python code, on Mac OS, that uses

```
import av
container = av.open( h264feed )
```

It fails with

`No handlers could be found for logger "libav.h264"`

I did:

```
brew install ffmpeg --with-openh264
pip install av
```

Is there any way to decode an h264 feed with python av ?